# Django project to Azure Cloud Services without Visual Studio

Tags: django, azure, deployment

I'm exploring MS Azure, and have a very simple one-app Django project that I'd like to use with Cloud Services, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've got the Node-based Azure cross-platform CLI tools installed, and I'm trying to figure out the process of creating the necessary infrastructure to stick the Django project on Azure Cloud Services (note: not Azure VM, not Azure Web Sites). The tutorials I've seen use Visual Studio to do this, but I'm on Mac/Linux.

There must be a process how to produce the necessary files (.cspkg, .cscfg etc.) without VS, but I haven't found any tutorials or documentation about it. How do you generate or construct those files, and any other boilerplate, without the use of VS, and what's the process of actually deploying the code to the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

best to use is powershell : you'll need "**New-AzureServiceProject**", "**Add-AzureDjangoWebRole**" and in the end you need to package it with **Save-AzureServiceProjectPackage**, afterwards you can upload it either through the portal or through powershell with the cmdlets **New-AzureService** and **"Publish-AzureServiceProject"** hope this helps you?

Comment: Upvoted for general helpfulness; I'm on Mac/Linux and not Windows, but as a last resort with a Windows virtual machine this is probably workable.