# Python azure module: how to create a new deployment

Tags: python, powershell, azure

azure.servicemanagmentservice.py contains:

```
def create_deployment(self, service_name, deployment_slot, name,
                          package_url, label, configuration,
                          start_deployment=False,
                          treat_warnings_as_error=False,
                          extended_properties=None):
```

What is `package_url` and `configuration`? Method comment indicates that

```
 package_url:
            A URL that refers to the location of the service package in the
            Blob service. The service package can be located either in a
            storage account beneath the same subscription or a Shared Access
            Signature (SAS) URI from any storage account.
....
configuration:
        The base-64 encoded service configuration file for the deployment.
```

All over the internet there are references to Visual Studio and Powershell to create those files. What do they look like? Can I manually create them? Can azure module create them? Why is Microsoft service so confusing and lacks documentation?

I am using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure Python Azure SDK. I am running Mac OS X on my dev box, so I don't have Visual Studio or cspack.exe.
Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So, there is the .cscfg info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee758710.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, it looks like you are trying to use [Python Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) to create a cloud service deployment. Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/doc/servicemanagement.rst) of how to use the create_deployment function.

> Can I manually create them? Can azure module create them?

If you mean you wanna know how to create an Azure deployment package of your Python app, based on my experience, there are several options you can leverage.

- If you have a visual studio, you can create a cloud project from projects’ template and package the project via 1 click. In VS, create new project -> cloud -> 
  [image]

Then package the project:
[image]

- Without VS, you can use [Microsoft Azure PowerShell cmdlets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/), or [cspack commandline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432988.aspx) tool to create a deployment package. Similar ask could be found at: [Django project to Azure Cloud Services without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407177/django-project-to-azure-cloud-services-without-visual-studio)

After you packaging the project, you would have the .cspkg file like this:
[image]

For your better reference, I have uploaded the testing project at:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7B27A151CFCEAF4F%21143283

As to the ‘configuration’, it means the base-64 encoded service configuration file (.cscfg) for the deployment
[image]

In Python, we can set up the ‘configuration’ via below code

```
configuration = base64.b64encode(open('E:\\TestProjects\\Python\\YourProjectFolder\\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg', 'rb').read())
```

Hope above info could provide you a quick clarification. Now, let’s go back to Python SDK itself and see how we can use create_deployment function to create a cloud service deployment accordingly.

Firstly, I’d like to suggest you to refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management/ to get the basic idea of what azure Service Management is and how it’s processing. 
In general, we can make create_deployment function work via 5 steps

1. Create your project’s deployment package and set up a [configuration file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee758710.aspx) (.cscfg) – (to have the quick test, you can use the one that I have uploaded)
2. Store your project’s deployment package in a Microsoft Azure Blob Storage account under the same subscription as the hosted service to which the package is being uploaded. Get the blob file’s URL (or use a Shared Access Signature (SAS) URI from any storage account). You can use [Azure storage explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) to upload the package file, and then it will be shown on Azure portal.
   [image]
3. Use OpenSSL to create your management certificate. It is needed to create two certificates, one for the server (a .cer file) and one for the client (a .pem file), the article I mentioned just now have provided a detailed info https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management/

Screenshot of my created certificates
[image]
Then, upload .cer certificate to Azure portal: SETTINGS -> management certificate tab -> click upload button (on the bottom of the page).

4. Create a cloud service in Azure and keep the name in mind.
5. Create another project to test Azure SDK - create_deployment, code snippet for your reference:

subscription_id = 'Your subscription ID That could be found in Azure portal'

certificate_path = 'E:\YourFoloder\mycert.pem'

```
sms = ServiceManagementService(subscription_id, certificate_path)

def TestForCreateADeployment():
    service_name = "Your Cloud Service Name"
    deployment_name = "name"
    slot = 'Production'
    package_url = ".cspkg file’s URL – from your blob"
    configuration = base64.b64encode(open('E:\\TestProjects\\Python\\ YourProjectFolder\\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg ', 'rb').read())
    label = service_name

    result = sms.create_deployment(service_name,
                 slot,
                 deployment_name,
                 package_url,
                 label,
                 configuration)

      operation = sms.get_operation_status(result.request_id)
      print('Operation status: ' + operation.status)
```

Here is running result’s screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clear. I am using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure to orchestrate creation of Azure clusters for my testing. I am not trying to package a Python app; I am using Python SDK for Azure to create VMs.
Also, I am doing my development on Mac OS X.
Thank you

Comment: Please note create_deployment method is used for deploying your code to a cloud service. To create a VM, please use create_virtual_machine_deployment method. Refer to [How to: Create a virtual machine] section of https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management/

Comment: Hm. I see. How about creating multiple VMs in one cloud service/deployment? I found that I cannot use multiple calls to create_virtual_machine_deployment() with the same cloud service name and same deployment name - I get Conflict Error. I found somewhere on SO, that I need to use add_role() method to add VMs to a deployment. My thought was to create a deployment, then add_role() several times to create my cluster.
I also tried create_virtual_machine_deployment() once and then add_role() - that did what I needed it to do. It's not clean, though. Am I misunderstanding how to use Azure SDK?

Comment: The answer depends on what kind of cloud platforms (IaaS or PaaS) you wanna use, if you prefer to use PaaS - cloud service , you can set up configuration via .cscfg file, i.e. if you want to have 10 instances (VMs) of a web role, set it likes <Role name="WebRole1"><Instances count="10" /></Role>, if you wanna use IaaS, then please note deployment_name must be unique among other deployments for the hosted service.

Comment: [It's not clean, though. Am I misunderstanding how to use Azure SDK?]          Here is the document: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/servicemanagement/servicemanagementservice.py provides a detailed description of every function, please check it and see if it helps.

Comment: If I cannot create .cscfg and .cspkg files (since I am working with Mac OS X), I am left with the following workflow? create_virtual_machine_deployment() once, then add_role() several times? Is there an alternative way (without using the .cscfg and .cspkg)?
Also, method names, create_virtual_machine_deployment() and create_deployment(). The "deployment" part in those methods - does it refer to the same concept of deployment? Do I correctly understand that one deployment can contain multiple VM instances?

Comment: I am using it as IaaS.

Comment: In Python SDK, create_virtual_machine_deployment doesn't required configuration (.cscfg) that create_deployment used.'Deployment' of [create_deployment] means uploading a new service package and creating a new deployment on cloud service's staging or production, while 'Deployment' of create_virtual_machine_deployment means provisioning a virtual machine based on the supplied settings. 1 cloud service could have deployments on staging and production, 1 deployment can have multiple instances (VMs).

Comment: As to PaaS cloud service itself, .csdef file specifies the service endpoints, and establishes configuration settings for the service. If you are not using PaaS (web role & work role) on Azure, it's not needed to generate .cscfg and .cspkg files. I wonder if there is any specified issue encountered when you use create_virtual_machine_deployment method (ensure the deployment_name is unique)?

Comment: A bit beyond our discussion here, if you are interest in VS, Azure has provided a Visual Studio image in public Azure virtual machine gallery:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/01/08/azure-virtual-machine-images-for-visual-studio.aspx, we can conveniently use that VM for developing & testing on VS. Also, you may wanna try VS code as well: https://code.visualstudio.com/